# HTML form to save TEXT and FILE at the same time

Tags: php, forms

I have been searching for a solution for the last 2 hours and couldn't find anything.

index.html

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type='file' name='imageFile' />
   <p>title it</p>
   <input type='text' id='post-title' name='title'/>
   <br />
   <button id='submit-file'>submit it</button>

 </form>
```

result.php

```
<?php
    $name= $_POST["title"];
    $filename = $_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]; 
    $tempname = $_FILES["imageFile"]["tmp_name"];     
        $folder = "images/".$filename; 


echo $filename;
echo '<br/>';
echo $tempname;
echo '<br/>';
echo $name;
?>
```

I was trying to save the file in "images" folder and at the same time want to display the text from the previous form.

It shows the file name, and the title ($name), but the file is not saving in the folder "images".

The purpose of this is to save text/link and image file to the SQL using a form.
I am not an expert in coding, so may be someone can help me.

Update: Found the solution.

```
<?php
    $name= $_POST["title"];
    $filename = $_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]; 
    $tempname = $_FILES["imageFile"]["tmp_name"];     
        $folder = "images/".$filename; 
if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  { 
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; 
        }else{ 
            $msg = "Failed to upload image"; }

echo $filename;
echo '<br/>';
echo $tempname;
echo '<br/>';
echo $name;

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code to save the image?..........see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Dude! I was trying to find a solution here also!